# How does the default netcore docker-compose template work?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I'm trying to understand how docker works. Today I tried do dockerise my netcore application, so I hit the `dockerize` button and it created the following Dockerfile for me:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyProj.sln ./
COPY MyProj.Console/MyProj.Console.csproj MyProj.Console/
COPY MyProj.Core/MyProj.Core.csproj MyProj.Core/
COPY MyProj.Solidity/MyProj.Solidity.csproj MyProj.Solidity/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyProj.Console
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProj.Console.dll"]
```

I actually don't understand this part:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyProj.sln ./
COPY MyProj.Console/MyProj.Console.csproj MyProj.Console/
COPY MyProj.Core/MyProj.Core.csproj MyProj.Core/
COPY MyProj.Solidity/MyProj.Solidity.csproj MyProj.Solidity/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
```

The main point here is: how does it even work? It just copies several `csproj` files to output directory, but I don't see any `cs` files. Where is the entire program logic? How is it supposed to work? I'm really trying hard to learn how it works, but I just can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the lines after the part that you dont' understand? It's

```
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyProj.Console
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app
```

The part that you pointed out copies the project files and then does a restore.  These lines copy the rest of your sources and do a build. The build includes an implicit restore, which becomes a no-op because the restore was already done.

The lines that you pointed out are an optimization  in the docker file. Docker will look at the files and timestamps to decide which steps need to be re-run. It caches the rest. Chances are your code changes on every rebuild but your project files change very little. So the docker can skip the restore on every build. But your sources will change very often so it will only build your sources instead of doing a restore *and* rebuilding your sources on every code change.